# Woo: Modifying premium plugin Ship to Multiple Addresses

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I'm using woo and the premium plugin Ship to Multiple Addresses.
https://woocommerce.com/document/multiple-ship-to-addresses/ (That is the only documentation from the developer)
Want to modify some texts and layouts, but the areas are not in the plugin’s templates and I cannot find the exact functions in the plugin’s files to modify.  When I think that I found the correct sections, I’m unable to get the filters or new functions to work in the child theme.

I have about 7 things that I want to do, but including all of that info and the codes gets really long. The top 3 are below.

Maybe there are also styles or scripts that I need to deregister/dequeue? Am I even on the right track? Am I missing something obvious?

Hopefully someone can help me. I appreciate the input.

Modifications involves content on the Checkout page, specifically the woo templates:
form-checkout.php, form-shipping.php, review-order.php

I have already accomplished some modifications with the plugin content by editing the more familiar woo hooks and templates.  But using the child theme to modify parts of the plugin has me stumped.
I don’t want to modify the plugin files every time an update occurs.

Initial Goals:

Involves plugin’s  files  woocommerce-shipping-multiple-addresses/ :
woocommerce-shipping-multiple-addresses.php
…/includes/wcms-notes.php

Changes to …/includes/wcms-notes.php

1. Modify the “Note” label. Replace the word “Note” with “Signature”
2. move the “Character Limit” to before the the text area, after the Note/Signature

```
Related to around line 150if ( $show_notes ):$limit = !empty( $wcms->gateway_settings['checkout_notes_limit'] ) ? absint( $wcms->gateway_settings['checkout_notes_limit'] ) : 0;?><div class="note-form"><label><?php _e( 'Note', 'wc_shipping_multiple_address' ); ?></label><textarea name="shipping_note[<?php echo $loop; ?>]" rows="2" cols="30" class="ms_shipping_note" data-index="<?php echo $loop; ?>" data-limit="<?php echo $limit; ?>"></textarea><?php if ( !empty( $limit ) ): ?><small><?php printf( __('Character Limit: %d', 'wc_shipping_multiple_address'), $limit ); ?></small><?php endif; ?></div><?phpendif;
```

Items in woo commerce-shipping-multiple-addresses.php

3. Modify the “Shipping Methods” text label to the word  “Recipients”

It is not wrapped in anything —  tag, div, or label;  appears as plain text.
I cannot exactly locate it in the plugin's files

```
Line 607 <tr class="multi_shipping"> <td style="vertical-align: top;" … > <?php _e( 'Shipping Methods', 'wc_shipping_multiple_address' ); ?>
```

I think it may be tied to  wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label function, but cannot figure it out.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13AS8.png)

Several different approaches.

Comment: FYI -- for #1, changing the "Note" Label -- I know that 
 <?php _e( 'Note', 'wc_shipping_multiple_address' ); ?>
  needs to be changed to 
_e( 'Signature', 'wc_shipping_multiple_address' );

Comment: #3 -- it is not related to the wc_cart_totals... -- it is only in the code.  The words "Shipping Methods" must be changed on <td style=".."><?php _e( 'Shipping Methods', 'wc_shipping_multiple_address' ); ?>

Comment: Solved #1 and #3 with -- function multi_change_translate_text( $translated ) { -- messier than I like, but it'll do for now.

Comment: So --  editing parts of:
…/woocommerce-shipping-multiple-addresses.php -- very close to the desired layout. How to accomplish in child theme?

Comment: $formatted_address = wcms_get_formatted_address( $package['destination'] );
        echo '<address>'. $formatted_address .'</address><br />'; ?>
<!-- customization -- modify MOVE HERE  --> <?php
$sess_cart_addresses = wcms_session_get( 'cart_item_addresses' );
if ( $sess_cart_addresses && !empty($sess_cart_addresses) ) {
echo '<p><a href="'. get_permalink($page_id) .'" class="modify-address-button">'. __( 'Modify address', 'wc_shipping_multiple_address' ) .'</a></p>';}?> 
        <?php 
        do_action( 'wc_ms_shipping_package_block'

Comment: AND then fully remove  --- remove all rates in address-block -- $ship_package['rates'] = array(); fully removed from only this specific div area. OR wrap it in a div class and hide via css.  // If at least one shipping method is available -- start section to remove information
        $ship_package['rates'] = array();

        foreach ( $package['rates'] as $rate ) {
         $ship_package['rates'][$rate->id] = $rate;